# Small black wire connected to both gold screws

Tags: electrical, receptacle

I’m replacing the receptacles and one has a small (about 2 inches) black wire connected on both ends to each of the gold screws.
In the holes in the back there is a black wire on top gold, red on bottom gold and the normal white and ground wire.

Is this safe? Should I replicate it when I install the new receptacle?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please add a photo of the outlet.

Comment: It sounds like someone removed the small metal tab between the two screws by mistake and used a jumper wire to reconnect them together.

Comment: Is there a wall switch? Does that switch *do anything*? My hunch is that this was a split receptacle - top always on, bottom switched. Someone didn't like that the bottom was switched. Rather than do the *correct* thing - rewire the switch to operate a ceiling light fixture directly, they disabled the switch so that the receptacle is always on and now the switch does nothing.

Comment: Having a red wire might make the circuit more complicated, than a normal pass though connection(where power goes to another outlet).

Comment: It’s interesting because it seems like all (or most of) the outlets in the house have a red wire and a black and a white!

Comment: Also I updated to add photos. Thanks for your help.

Comment: There is a wall switch, but it only turns on the ceiling lights to my knowledge.

Comment: Then the other *likely* alternative is: Half-switched (as I previously described). Switch changed to switch ceiling light. **But red wire left in place**. Way to test: Turn of the breaker. Disconnect the red wire - note that you will never be able to put in the backstab again, but we don't care because you are replacing the receptacle anyway. Cap it with a wire nut for safety. Turn on the breaker. Carefully check if the receptacles work. If you can, check if the red wire is dead - ideally a non-contact voltage tester should show nothing but should show voltage on the black.

Comment: The black wire in the back stab is stripped too far back leaving bare wire exposed. The wire on the top screw is wrapped around the screw the wrong way - it should be wrapped clockwise so it's pulled into the screw as it's tightened - the way it is, it'll be pushed out as tightened. Can you add a picture into the back of the box so we can see how the wires are connected in the box? It almost appears that the red & one black are connected together.

Comment: @crip659 I see the tab still there though, in the 2nd pic, unless that's some kind of optical illusion.

Answer (score 2):

That is a jumper which is connecting the hot contacts of the two receptacles of this duplex receptacle. It would appear to be unnecessary in this case and you could remove it. I think the receptacle would function as it does with the jumper in place.

However, it is not doing any harm and you could just leave it there.

A jumper like this is normally used to join the two receptacles when the metal link connecting the two receptacles has been removed, but it appears that the tab in this receptacle is in place.

However, it could be that the tab is damaged and partly broken, but I cannot tell from the picture. That little tab between the screws is intended to be broken intentionally by bending it back and forth IF one wants to separate the two receptacles. Later if someone wants to restore the connection a jumper is used like the one here.

The wiring of this receptacle does not look correct. It may be working OK but it is not standard wiring. It could be this house has some "multi-wire branch circuits". These use one white neutral and two hots, one black and one red, but connected a special way. This is not the way and this could lead to a short circuit and tripped breakers if some wires are changed elsewhere.

EDIT

Here is what could cause a problem with this wiring. The black hot and the red hot could be on separate breakers on the same leg. In other words this might be fed by two breakers--NOT ALLOWED.

Or they might be fed by the same breaker by a parallel path. Also not  allowed.

What could be done to investigate this possibility is to disconnect either the black or the red and test each wire for voltage. If you find both of them hot (and disconnected from each other), then you must continue to investigate because this is not acceptable.

If one is not hot when disconnected from the other, then you need to find out where the not hot wire is going because it should have a neutral with it and there is only one neutral white present. No doubt experts on miswiring can suggest how to proceed with this investigation.

Comment: Your comment about the jumper being unnecessary assumes that both the red and black wires coming into the box/outlet are hot.  That may not be the case.

Comment: @SteveSh What are the possibilities for the red and black wires? Both hot on the same leg or one is unconnected. (The OP does not state that the receptacle is not working so I  assume it was working.)  Doesn't the connecting tab appear to be intact? The jumper wire is superfluous.

Comment: I looked closer and agree the connecting tab appears to be intact. 

I put my new receptacle on mimicking the black and red wires as they are in the photo (just around the screws instead of backstabbing), but I did not put the jumper wire back on. The outlet is working and I used a tester that shows the wiring is “correct”. 

Still confused about why there are red wires everywhere… but not confident enough to mess with what’s currently there.

Comment: @gs716  Do you know if you have conduit for separate wires or cable?  With cable the red is odd and needs investigating.  Conduit could be a bit easier, but a single white(neutral) is odd also.  The extra red is usually just used for switch circuits or MWBC or 240v circuits.

Comment: I have edited my answer.

Comment: I would look in the panel and see if any breakers are off, either manually switched off or tripped  to off. If one or more breakers is off, DO NOT SWITCH IT ON. If your house was originally wired with a bunch of multi-wire branch circuits that were subsequently rewired to standard, whoever did that may have just switched off breakers to disconnect one leg or a breaker might have tripped. If a breaker like that was switched on, it would make a short between hots on different legs, i.e., a 240 V short. The breakers should just trip, but you don't want to do it.

Comment: Would like to see a picture of your panel with the door open but the dead front in place. Could you edit your original post to add this pic? I am NOT suggesting that you remove the "dead front" but just to open the door and photograph the entire set of breakers.